# 301 redirect not working on click only on refresh or new window

Tags: redirect, seo, http-status-code-301

I have a website that I am working on closing and merging into another. I've set some 301 redirects to the site I am merging into but they don't work on click, only when I open in a new tab or window or refresh the redirected page url. Any idea what could be causing this?

Example..https://www.flexor.is/services when you click on the pic labeled Hönd/Úlnliður/Fingur with the picture of the hand, nothing happens other than I go to the old url. If I open in new window or tab the redirect sends me to the new site.

Answer (score 0):

When I saved the site locally, the problem was not occurring but I got some errors although I used the 'base href' property. So, I feel that the problem is occurring due to some javascripts and if you are using wix then you have no access to the javascripts directly. Therefore, you can use:
(i) Use `target="_blank"` instead of `target="_top"`
**OR**
(ii)Use the link you want to reach directly instead of 301 redirect.

Comment: Thank you very much! Does this have an impact on SEO? Do search engines still follow the 301 defined even though the link is dierct?

Comment: You are welcome. Using 301 redirect don't lose Page Rank anymore, and is also recommended for SEO. And search engines do follow the 301 redirected link if it is used in the page.